# Show recent streaming values in Card of a Power Bi Desktop(report)

Tags: powerbi

I am getting real time data as shown below

```
A   B   Datetime
20  76  2018-04-01T21:04:22Z
21  75  2018-04-01T21:04:32Z
20  75  2018-04-01T21:04:42Z
20  75  2018-04-01T21:04:52Z
21  76  2018-04-01T21:05:02Z
```

I need to plot A and B on a line Chart which is easy to do and along with this need to show the latest value on a Card as well. But when I try to show the values on the Card, it show the summation values of 102 and 377 instead of 21 and 76 which are the last and recent values.

I am working in `Power BI Desktop` and using a streaming Dataset. I cannot create new tables since with real time data you can only create measures.

How can we show the latest values on a card in a Power BI desktop.? I am looking for a solution for a report not a dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the Datetime to the 'Visual level filters', and then filter the 'Top 1' of the latest Datetime.

I can't test this on a streaming dataset, but since you're in PBI Desktop and using a Card Visual, I assume this option is available.

[image: Power BI]

Answer (score 0):

You can write measures to find the latest values for `A` and `B`:

```
Latest A = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[A]), LASTDATE(Table1[Datetime]))
Latest B = CALCULATE(MAX(Table1[B]), LASTDATE(Table1[Datetime]))
```